# Just updated plugins for Jenkins and now Jenkins won't start

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

We updated three plugins for jenkins. After they were updated jenkins will not start. We get jenkins.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=5/NOTINSTALLED and jenkins.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE. Any ideas what this error could be or perhaps suggest a starting place to find the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the issue was that somehow installing the plugin update removed JAVA from the system path.

Answer (score 1):

details and solution for this issue,

********************** Details******************

jenkins.service - Jenkins Continuous Integration Server
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/jenkins.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Mon 2023-05-** 19:29:07 Time Zone; *** ago
Process: 10500 ExecStart=/usr/bin/jenkins (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Main PID: 10500 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

```
                            **Solution:**
                             (six steps)
```

Follow the steps below,

1. sudo amazon-linux-extras install java-openjdk11
   Then check
2. sudo update-alternatives --config java
   It should give you Java-installed versions
   In my case, I have installed Java as,
   Selection    Command

---

*+ 1           java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64 (/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.362.b08-1.amzn2.0.1.x86_64/jre/bin/java)
2           java-11-openjdk.x86_64 (/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.18.0.10-1.amzn2.0.1.x86_64/bin/java)

3. Enter to keep the current selection[+], or type selection number: 2

Set path for java in the vim /etc/profile as
4. export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.18.0.10-1.amzn2.0.1.x86_64

5. double-check with the below commands
   source /etc/profile
   echo $JAVA_HOME
   echo $JAVA_HOME will give output as
   /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.18.0.10-1.amzn2.0.1.x86_64
6. sysytemctl start Jenkins
   It will show
   jenkins.service - Jenkins Continuous Integration Server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/jenkins.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2023-05-** 19:45:23 time ZONE; **s ago
   Main PID: 20239 (java)
   CGroup: /system.slice/jenkins.service
   └─20239 /usr/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar /usr/share/java/jenkins.war --webroot=%C/jenkins/war --httpPort=8080